# The underlying connection has been closed: Unexpected error while sending

Tags: powershell, invoke

I tried the following code to request an XML file from my Firewall.

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest "https://IpAddress"
```

i get this error:
    Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection has been closed: Unexpected error while sending.

i tried this:

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@

    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

and this

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

It is still not working.
Kind regards

Comment: Does it work if you use a web browser instead?

Comment: Try combining with `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls,Tls11,Tls12'`